# Effective login control for program?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, authentication

This is for a mini project at school, using c# in vs2012. My main form consists of a log-in panel and buttons which open child forms. Since I know nothing about security of log-in pages, I find it convenient to have a log-in panel and the main controls all in the same form. While you are not logged in, the buttons will remain disabled. If you log in as admin, all buttons will enable, and only some of them if you logged in as employee. Is it effective, or does it compromise security and do I need to make a separate form for it? Below is my verify function, ran when the Log-in button is clicked.

```
 public void verify()
        {
            con.Open();

            lblNotify.Text = "";
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS where username = '" + txtUser.Text + "' AND pass = HASHBYTES('SHA1','" + txtPass.Text + "');", con);
            if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
            {
                lblNotify.Text = "Incorrect username or password. Try again.";
            }
            else
            {
                btnLogin.Enabled = false;
                btnLogout.Enabled = true;
                lblNotify.Text = "You are currently logged in as " + txtUser.Text + ".";
                if (txtUser.Text == "admin"){
                panelMenu.Enabled = true;
                txtUser.Enabled = false;
                txtPass.Enabled = false;
                }


            }

            con.Close();
        }
        //login
        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            verify();
        }
```

I included a screenshot in case needed.
[image]

Comment: Use prepared statement to prevent SQL Injection so people can't get admin access with your current form.

Comment: You should use SQL parameters instead of embedding the parameters in the query. A username like `'; select 1; --` can be used to "hack" your form.

Comment: @Prix  ok i'll look into Sql injection, thanks. But seeing it did not bother you that my buttons are just "enabled" and "disabled", does it mean it's fine that way?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that but as your SQL is right now it's easy to get admin.

Comment: Provided you check that the user has actually been authenticated in the OnClick event of the buttons, then you will be fine.  If the button opens the form regardless of whether or not a user has been authenticated, Memory Editing the process could enable the button **without** any authentication.
EDIT: If it is a school project then it really wouldn't matter too much.